# Are the instance variables the new global variables?

Tags: oop

lately I'm having the feeling that instances variables have the same problems of global variables, I googled about this and found [this old article](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/172) that more or less describes the potential problem i'm seeing.

What good practices do you use to avoid that the same problems of global variables affect instance variables or class variables?

Comment: The link is no longer valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes are much smaller than global structure so the impact of an instance variable is much smaller.  By keeping small class sizes and adhering closely to the single responsibility principle, much of the downside of a global variable is averted.  If the instance variable is created from a passed in parameter then I often make that parameter required in the constructor making the dependency explicit.  Also the instance variable is encapsulated well, never being directly modified outside of the instance's methods making it very easy to determine where the instance variable is modified.  Finally the instance variable must make sense to the class as a whole or must be private.

Answer (score 0):

Instance variables are only accessible within a specific class.  So to prevent instance variables being used too widely, keep classes small.  If a class grows large, decide if parts of it that can be refactored into another, smaller class, that the original class uses.

Answer (score 0):

Nor Instance variables nor global variables nor any kind of variable have "problems"... They are all tools. The problem is that sometimes a lot of programmers choose to use the "wrong tool". You have to think carefully what your choices mean, so you can make the right choice.

Using a global variable for something, like CurrentUserName... Means that you are saying that he CurrentUserName is something universally know. And that "there can be only one" CurrentUserName at each time. And that will probably be false if you ever want to allow to users to be logged at the same time (unless you get really lucky, and both users have the same name)...

A realted wrong use with instance variables is if you put the e-mail address of a User as an instance variable, and you then realize that each user can have multiple e-mail addresses.

I'd also give an example with inheritance, because  I think it'll make it more clear:
A related problem with inheritance is for example if you are modeling the typical Student, Teacher problem, and you try making Student a subclass of Person and Teacher a subclass of Person. And then you realize that some persons might be both...

Student inheriting from Person is a static relationship that can't be changed at runtime. And Student and Teachers aren't static relationships... A person can be neither, and then start being a student, and then start being a teacher, and then stop being both, and yet it'll always be the same person, and that model can't handle that....

Coming back to the user, the user is "associated" with multiple e-mails account... If you put an instance variable you are stating that he is just "associated" with a single e-mail account, and you are contradicting your problem domain, and that's why you'll have problem...

The same applies if you say there is just a globally known current user name....

The problem in all cases is that you have a problem domain, and you are modeling it wrong... You have to make your program, and your model, behave similar to the problem domain.... If you don't do it, you'll have problems, whichever tool you choose to solve your problem.

BTW: I also think that User having a list of e-mail address is wrong, but that's for an entirely different set of motives. I'd actually use a

```
class ContactInformation
{
    User contact;
    EMailAddress email;
}
```

and remember that objects don't "own" nor "have" other objects... That's an implementation decision... Objects just "know" other objects...